# WPF Xaml, Being able to select the textbox and whole view. While being able to copy the contents of the textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a list of textboxs in a listview. When I click on the Textbox the Listview selection does not change. I have to click next to the TextBox to select the listview item. I want to be able to copy the content of the textbox while also being able to select it.

Is there any way of doing this?

```
    <TextBox 
           TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" 
           Text="{Binding Path=Note, Mode=OneWay}" 
           Width="512" MinWidth="512" MinHeight="70" 
           IsReadOnly="True"
           TextElement.FontWeight="DemiBold" Background="Transparent"    
           BorderThickness="0"
     />
```

This is what I have so far.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1P05fAPXXzwpc6Iy8hRnzZmZVVJVhnni3/view?usp=sharing

A picture of what I am talking about

I would really like to stay only in xaml/wpf

EDIT: SOLUTION for listview or the answer below for anyone

```
    <ListView.Resources>
         <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
              <Style.Triggers>
                   <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True"> <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
                    </Trigger>
               </Style.Triggers>
           </Style>
        </ListView.Resources>
```

Comment: I don't get it, that's the default behaviour and even with your code you should be able to do it. Also, your title looks unrelated to the question

Comment: I uploaded this picture to show my issue better. I want to be able to highlight the messages content, but it doesn't select the whole tab around it because it's a textbox. If I click on the outside first it highlights the whole tab then I can highlight the contents. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MmAiQ5ijWk7GTPlWJ_dCS8p7gLuIleza/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @JakeYoung You need to describe in plain, simple English what "the whole view" means to you personally. Nobody but you knows what you mean by that phrase. You need to explain it. You need to explain in detail what part of your user interface "the view" is. You need to explain it so I can tell exactly what parts of what control(s) **are** part of "the view", and exactly what parts of what control(s) **are not** part of "the view". If it is a good explanation, i should be able to pick any given pixel in your screenshot and tell you if it is **inside** "the view" or **outside** "the view".

Comment: And you need to do the same with "selection".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your snippet looks fine.  Setting `IsReadOnly="True"` should allow you to select and copy the content, but not edit it.  Note, however, that the context menu will only appear when you right-click on a selected range of text.  This seems to be a consequence of marking the text box read-only: if none of the 'Copy', 'Cut', and 'Paste' commands are available, it just won't show the menu.  'Copy' is only available when you right-click a selection, and 'Cut' and 'Paste' are only available if the box is editable.

---

I haven't been able to view your mockup image, as Google Drive is blocked here, but it sounds like you want to be able to display a message while allowing the user to highlight the entire message and copy it to the clipboard.  In that case, the quickest solution might be a simple custom control.

The example below *should* give you what you want.  Copying to clipboard should work with the context menu and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

**MessagePane.cs:**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace WpfTest
{
    [ContentProperty("Message")]
    public class MessagePane : Control
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextWrappingProperty =
            TextBlock.TextWrappingProperty.AddOwner(
                typeof(MessagePane),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(TextWrapping.WrapWithOverflow));

        public TextWrapping TextWrapping
        {
            get { return (TextWrapping)GetValue(TextWrappingProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextWrappingProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty MessageProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                "Message",
                typeof(string),
                typeof(MessagePane),
                new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

        public string Message
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(MessageProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MessageProperty, value); }
        }

        static MessagePane()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(
                typeof(MessagePane),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MessagePane)));

            CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding(
                typeof(MessagePane),
                new CommandBinding(
                    ApplicationCommands.Copy,
                    (sender, args) =>
                    {
                        var messagePane = sender as MessagePane;
                        if (messagePane != null)
                            Clipboard.SetText(messagePane.Message);
                    }));
        }

        protected override void OnPreviewMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Focus();
            base.OnPreviewMouseDown(e);
        }
    }
}
```

**Themes\Generic.xaml:**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:l="clr-namespace:WpfTest">
  <Style TargetType="l:MessagePane">
    <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="TextWrapping"
            Value="WrapWithOverflow" />
    <Setter Property="Padding"
            Value="3,2" />
    <Setter Property="Focusable"
            Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="l:MessagePane">
          <Border x:Name="MessageBorder"
                  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                  BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                  BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                  Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
            <Border.ContextMenu>
              <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Command="{x:Static ApplicationCommands.Copy}" />
              </ContextMenu>
            </Border.ContextMenu>
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="{TemplateBinding TextWrapping}"
                       Text="{TemplateBinding Message}" />
          </Border>
          <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsFocused"
                     Value="True">
              <Setter TargetName="MessageBorder"
                      Property="Background"
                      Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" />
              <Setter TargetName="MessageBorder"
                      Property="BorderBrush"
                      Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ActiveBorderBrushKey}}" />
            </Trigger>
          </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

The build action for `Themes\Generic.xaml` should be 'Page'.  You will also need to make sure your `AssemblyInfo.cs` contains a `ThemeInfo` attribute.  If you don't have one, just use this:

```
[assembly: ThemeInfo(
    // Where theme specific resource dictionaries are located
    // (used if a resource is not found in the page, or application
    // resource dictionaries)
    ResourceDictionaryLocation.None,

    // Where the generic resource dictionary is located
    // (used if a resource is not found in the page, app, or 
    // any theme specific resource dictionaries)                                 
    ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly 
)]
```

**Usage Example:**

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
  <l:MessagePane Message="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ..." />
  <l:MessagePane Message="Sed eu sem egestas, lobortis orci at..." />
  <l:MessagePane Message="Vivamus in turpis metus ..." />
</StackPanel>
```

[image: Screenshot]

---

#### Alternate ListView-Based Solution

If you simply want to display these messages in an `ItemsControl` (like a `ListView`), you don't even need the code above.  You can do it pretty simply:

```
<ListView x:Name="_messageList"
          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
  <ListView.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static ApplicationCommands.Copy}"
                    Executed="OnCopyCommandExecuted" />
  </ListView.CommandBindings>
  <ListView.ItemsSource>
    <x:Array Type="s:String">
      <s:String>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit ...</s:String>
      <s:String>Sed eu sem egestas, lobortis orci at, commodo erat ...</s:String>
      <s:String>Vivamus in turpis metus. Nullam metus lectus ...</s:String>
    </x:Array>
  </ListView.ItemsSource>
  <ListView.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="C"
                Modifiers="Control"
                Command="{x:Static ApplicationCommands.Copy}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, ElementName=_messageList}" />
  </ListView.InputBindings>
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Border Background="Transparent">
        <Border.ContextMenu>
          <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Command="{x:Static ApplicationCommands.Copy}"
                      CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
          </ContextMenu>
        </Border.ContextMenu>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                   TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" />
      </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Command handler in the code-behind:

```
private void OnCopyCommandExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var message = e.Parameter as string;
    if (message != null)
        Clipboard.SetText(message);
}
```

Comment: I don't need to edit the messages, but I just want to be able to highlight the messages themselves. But I also want the rest of the display the be highlighted itself. I'm not sure if I am describing this enough.

Comment: Right, that's what I inferred from your post: you want to be able to select and copy the content, but not edit it.  That should work as written, with the caveats I mentioned.

Comment: @JakeYoung FWIW that description makes no sense at all to me: What is "the rest of the display"? Maybe you need to do wireframes with extensive descriptions of exactly what steps you want the user to take, and what your UI should do in response: "User right clicks on the second word of the first message, context menu pops up with Copy and Select All commands" -- something on that level of specificity.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MmAiQ5ijWk7GTPlWJ_dCS8p7gLuIleza/view?usp=sharing Here is a picture I took. I want to be able to highlight the content of the message, but I guess because it's a textbox it doesn't select the whole view.

Comment: @JakeYoung Additions to your question should go in your question. SO takes a dim view of links to off-site resources. We very often find that those links go dead in time, leaving the question incoherent. N.B. Please read my previous comment again. When people are telling you that your descriptions are too ambiguous, please do not introduce new ambiguous terms. I have no way of knowing what "select the whole view" means to you. No possible way.

Comment: Okay sorry about that. I have limited resources to upload pictures right now and can re-uploaded later. I thought the picture would help with the description and I updated the description a bit. I'm not entirely sure what the view is called.

Comment: @JakeYoung I can't see the image you uploaded, but I think I get what you mean.  See my revised answer.

Comment: @MikeStrobel I'm pretty positive you did what I need, but I already have a bunch of stuff in my xaml and I don't want to make a whole big change..... Is there any way I could upload my xaml code for you to take a look at? Or do I need to create this new class and use that.

Comment: @JakeYoung The `MessagePane` class is meant to replace your usage of `TextBox`.  I'm afraid I can't look at your Xaml, as all file sharing sites are blocked here, including sites like Pastebin.  It shouldn't be a _huge_ change, though, and it should be mostly additive.  It should also be trivial to roll back if you're using version control.  If you're _not_ using version control, fix that first :).

Comment: @MikeStrobel How/where do I add that Themes\Generic.xaml and how do I incorporate it into my own xaml?

Comment: By default, WPF should look for default styles inside `[project root]\Themes`, with the file name being `[theme name].xaml`.  Use 'generic' as the theme name if you don't want to do separate styles for the different system themes (don't bother with this).  The build action should be 'Page', and the other properties should be more or less the same as for a `UserControl`.  I'm also going to add an addendum to my answer that describes an assembly-wide attribute you need to define.

Comment: @MikeStrobel I really appreciate the help! Your stuff works but my latest problem is because I have all my code inside of a listview... It won't let me select and copy the messages. Any ideas?

Comment: @JakeYoung If you're putting the messages in a `ListView`, that simplifies things.  You don't need the custom control at all in that case.  I added an alternate solution at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: @MikeStrobel do you possibly have an email I can email you my code? That is a lot different then what I already have. I know you said you are pretty restricted on what you can do. I really appreciate the help, but I am still a novice.

Comment: I suppose I could dig out my old ThinkPad and load it up at home.  Upload it  wherever you like and either post a link here or e-mail it to me.  My address is <first name DOT last name AT gmail>.

Comment: You won't believe it, but I was able to get it to work with very little work... I appreciate all the help. If there's anything I can do for you please let me know. I just needed to add a listview.resource and added some style triggers